# Multiple issues trying to install PyBOSSA

Tags: redis, crowdsourcing, pybossa

I am trying to set up PyBOSSA on an AWS EC2 instance running Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. I am following [the official instructions](https://docs.pybossa.com/installation/guide/) and have encountered three errors so far.

1. sudo apt-get install -y git postgresql postgresql-all postgresql-server-dev-all libpq-dev python-psycopg2 libsasl2-dev libldap2-dev libssl-dev python-virtualenv python-dev build-essential libjpeg-dev libssl-dev libffi-dev dbus libdbus-1-dev libdbus-glib-1-dev libldap2-dev libsasl2-dev python-pip python3-pip redis-server
2. cd ~
3. git clone --recursive https://github.com/Scifabric/pybossa
4. cd pybossa
5. virtualenv -p python3 env (I'm using Python3 explicitly as my system also has Python 2.7 installed).
6. source env/bin/activate
7. pip install -U pip
8. pip install -r ~/pybossa/requirements.txt

At this point, I start getting error messages... I have copied the stdout and stderr into a file, which I have [uploaded here](https://ionthesky.s3-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/pip+install+-r+requirements.txt).

I'm not sure if the errors there are what have caused my later errors, but I pushed on through the instructions anyway in hopes it'd work...

1. cp settings_local.py.tmpl settings_local.py
2. cp alembic.ini.template alembic.ini
3. redis-server contrib/sentinel.conf --sentinel

I noted that the Redis server version was 4.0.9 (the instructions say it needs to be v2.6 or greater).

The output from starting the Redis server was as follows:

```
30284:X 30 Mar 03:09:22.004 # oO0OoO0OoO0Oo Redis is starting oO0OoO0OoO0Oo
30284:X 30 Mar 03:09:22.004 # Redis version=4.0.9, bits=64, commit=00000000, modified=0, pid=30284, just started
30284:X 30 Mar 03:09:22.004 # Configuration loaded
```

...I gather that's ok...

1. rqscheduler --host 127.0.0.1

This command wasn't installed on my system. I tried to use apt to install it, but there was nothing there. I also tried apt install rq rqscheduler rq-scheduler - nothing found. I then Googled and found the website for rq-scheduler, and found that I could install it by running `pip install rq-scheduler`

That installed correctly. Nonetheless, running the command `rqscheduler --host 127.0.0.1` in the terminal still failed: `rqscheduler: command not found`.

Knowing that it was a Python package, I wondered if maybe I needed to prepend python3 onto the start of the command: `python3 rqscheduler --host 127.0.0.1`. Response: `python3: can't open file 'rqscheduler': [Errno 2] No such file or directory`.

I also tried `pip3 install rq-scheduler` (which installed fine) and then running the command, but encountered the same error.

I would appreciate knowing how to get that running, but for the purpose of this test, I skipped setting up Regis and the scheduler, and continued with the PyBOSSA instructions:

1. sudo su postgres
2. createuser -d -P pybossa
3. (Password set)
4. createdb pybossa -O pybossa
5. exit
6. python3 cli.py db_create

...and then I got this error:

```
  File "cli.py", line 162
    '''SELECT id, created FROM task_run WHERE created LIKE ('\x%')''')
    ^
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 54-55: truncated \xXX escape
```

I instead tried `python cli.py db_create`, just in case it'd work, and got a different error:

```
python cli.py db_create
ValueError: invalid \x escape
```

So I'm seeing three separate issues:

1. Installing the PyBOSSA-required Python packages.
2. The issue with the rqscheduler command.
3. The error when starting the PyBOSSA server.

What do these errors mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 ) For the installation, try this:

```
virtualenv env 
source env/bin/activate
sudo apt install python3-pip
pip3 install -r requirements.txt
```

Which ended with no error.

---

2) Try :

```
pip install rq-scheduler==0.9.1
```

or

```
pip3 install rq-scheduler==0.9.1
```

---

3) The `\` char need to be escaped (like `\\`) in python.

So you may alter the `cli.py` line 162 (using text editor) from:

```
 '''SELECT id, created FROM task_run WHERE created LIKE ('\x%')''')
```

To:

```
 '''SELECT id, created FROM task_run WHERE created LIKE ('\\x%')''')
```

But it will be better to be fixed by dev on github ...

---

CONCLUSION

According to [official documentation](https://docs.pybossa.com/),

> PYBOSSA for python 3 We’ve finally migrated PYBOSSA to python 3. We’re
>   not going to merge into master until we test it in production a bit
>   more, so please, help us by testing it. All you have to do is
>   basically, check out the python3 branch (migrate-python3) and run it.
>   Then, any bug, issue you find, you just report it and we will be happy
>   to help you.

The PYBOSSA python3 version is freshly migrated so finaly is not very stable ... I expect that it will be better to use [the PYBOSSA python2.7 branch](https://github.com/Scifabric/pybossa/tree/python2.7) and follow exactly the documentation.

And according to [official github account](https://github.com/Scifabric/pybossa) they try to make money with support (?...)

> Get professional support You can hire us to help you with your PYBOSSA
>   project or server (specially for python 2.7). Go to our website, and
>   contact us.

Comment: Thanks, this solved all of the errors I had in the OP.
I've now encountered another issue (wherein the server appears to start, but I can't actually get it to open in my web browser). I'll try using the Python2.7 version instead. If that doesn't fix it, I'll open a separate question here on S/O.

Thanks heaps for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The issue has now been fixed for the master branch (https://github.com/Scifabric/pybossa/pull/1986). You can fetch the new code and use it.